# Return a list of values if column value matches else add 0 in list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I just tried for loop but it doesn't work,
where my data is,

```
      label_count  label     aging_period
0            21     good          0-3
1             1      TNR          3-6
2            80  average          3-6
3            19      bad          3-6
4            75     good          3-6
5            13     TOTB          6-9
6           104  average          6-9
7           128      bad          6-9
8            56     good          6-9
9            12     TOTB         9-12
10          101  average         9-12
11          275      bad         9-12
12           35     good         9-12
13            5     TOTB        12-24
14           26  average        12-24
15           46      bad        12-24
16           20     good        12-24
17            1     TOTB          24+
18            1  average          24+
19            3     good          24+
```

I want a list of values like,

```
average =  [0, 80, 104, 101, 26, 1]
   bad = [0, 19, 128, 275, 46, 0]
```

Now since there is no average for 0-3 so add 0.

I mean for each 'aging_period' and for each label if data present then add his coressponding label_count else add 0 in a list

Comment: There is data present in every cell for "label". What defines data present (or not present)?

Answer (score 2):

You can using `pivot` then `fillna`

```
df.pivot('label','aging_period','label_count').fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[557]: 
aging_period  0-3  12-24  24+  3-6  6-9  9-12
label                                        
TNR             0      0    0    1    0     0
TOTB            0      5    1    0   13    12
average         0     26    1   80  104   101
bad             0     46    0   19  128   275
good           21     20    3   75   56    35
```

Then slice the index you need

```
nedf=df.pivot('label','aging_period','label_count').fillna(0).astype(int)
nedf.loc['average'].tolist()
Out[559]: [0, 26, 1, 80, 104, 101]
```